# how can i write a node to subscribe to the “joint 0”？

Tags: ros, node, topic, joint-states

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I used a 6-DOF Arms of a Mobile Robot
in the topic  "joint_state"    three are messages of joint0  joint1 joint2.。。。joint6
how  can I write a node subscribe  to  joint 0； **only** “ joint 0”

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/260430/how-can-i-write-a-node-to-subscribe-to--the-%E2%80%9Cjoint-0%E2%80%9D%EF%BC%9F/) by [buaawanggg](https://answers.ros.org/users/30181/buaawanggg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-04-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You have a single topic called `/joint_states` that has, presumbably, [sensor_msgs/JointState](http://docs.ros.org/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/JointState.html) messages being published on it. I'm unsure if you are trying to say that a single message published on the topic contains information on all 6 joints (i.e. the `name` field would have 6 entries in it, which is pretty common), or if you are saying that every 6th message published on the topic is for `joint0`. Either way, as far as I know, it is not possible to filter topics at the subscriber level like you are interested in doing. I can think of two easy ways of working around this: (i) pulling out just the information for `joint0` in your callback (if there is no `joint0` info, just exit the callback), or (ii) writing an intermediate node that subscribes to `/joint_states`, filters out the `joint0` information, and then publishes just that info on a separate topic.

**EDIT**

Here's a simple example in Python to illustrate the concept:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import rospy
from sensor_msgs.msg import JointState
from std_msgs.msg import Float64

def joint_states_callback(message):
    # filter out joint0 position:
    for i,name in enumerate(message.name):
        if name == "joint0":
            pos = message.position[i]
            pub.publish(pos)
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    rospy.init_node("example_repub")
    pub = rospy.Publisher("joint0_topic", Float64, queue_size=1)
    rospy.Subscriber("joint_states", JointState, joint_states_callback, queue_size=1)
    rospy.spin()
```

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2017-04-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [buaawanggg](https://answers.ros.org/users/30181/buaawanggg/) on 2017-04-27**:
sorry i am not quite understand  what  “every 6th message published on the topic is for joint0”  mean
but i think what i want to  express one message contains information all 6 joints

**Comment by [buaawanggg](https://answers.ros.org/users/30181/buaawanggg/) on 2017-04-27**:
how  i can write in a node to filters out the joint0 information ？ only joint0，i want to only publish the position message of joint0 to another topic thx!

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2017-04-27**:
I added a simple example. Hopefully that helps.

**Comment by [buaawanggg](https://answers.ros.org/users/30181/buaawanggg/) on 2017-04-27**:
thx!!!!!!!

**Comment by [buaawanggg](https://answers.ros.org/users/30181/buaawanggg/) on 2017-05-03**:
thank you for your help！  i try to write this with C++  but there are some questions ，can you give me some  advice in my latest question，thx a lot！